# Threads and UserInterface interaction

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that lets the user log his location into a web server, I'm stuck in the flow of all this.
I'm using some threads but it is confusing at this point how to best use them for this.
On the main thread(1) there is the UI and the user hits the button to log location, then after hitting that button, the UI thread shows a "please wait" dialog box and starts a new thread(2) to acquire the gps location.
As I understand it right now: The UI thread is now stuck showing the dialog box and the thread(2) is getting the location. Next when thread(2) is done geting the location, I need another thread(3) to communicate with the http server.
As I understand it, the main thread(1) can't deal with any "sleep()" to periodically check on flags that the other threads will set for it.
So the only way to dismiss the "please wait" dialog is from one of the threads. So as you guys can see I'm a little confused.
Which will be the best way to address this (strictly talking about thread synchronization)?
Basically I need a User Interface that shows a please wait dialog while in the background the app is 1st getting GPS coordinates and 2nd, after getting the location logging it on an web server.
And finally showing a success or not to the user.
Thanks!

Comment: Say hello to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` which @vikram commented. `Activity.runOnUiThread()` is another option. `View.post()` is yet another.